# Submit more forms with one button in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, forms, jsp, jakarta-ee

I try to submit two forms with one button, but value of first form(input) is null.

**test.jsp**

```
<body>
            <script>
                function submitAllForms(){

                    console.log($('input[name=valueDateFromFilter]').val());
                    console.log($('input[name=valueDateToFilter]').val());

                    document.formDateFromFilter.submit();
                    document.formDateToFilter.submit();
                };
            </script>

                <form method="post" action="./Servlet" name="formDateFromFilter">
                    <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" name="valueDateFromFilter">
                </form>

                <form method="post" action="./Servlet" name="formDateToFilter">
                    <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" name="valueDateToFilter">
                </form>

            <a class="btn" href="#" onclick="submitAllForms();"><i class="icon-message"></i></a>

        </body>
```

**doPost method in Servlet.jsp**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
  String a = request.getParameter("valueDateFromFilter");
  String b = request.getParameter("valueDateToFilter");
  System.out.println(a);
  System.out.println(b);
}
```

In browser console i see values of both strings, but in the server log console value of first string (variable a) is null

Answer (score 0):

This is poor design and probably won't work. The better way to do it would be to build a JSP/servlet that receives both sets of data and calls the other servlets with the appropriate fields programatically on the server side